# Windows 10 back up HDD to VHD on a schedule

Tags: windows, backup

I am looking to backup my primary operating system to a secondary location in case of drive failure, and am looking for the least amount of down-time if the failure happens in the middle of the day.

I was running an SSD, and I was backing it up every morning to a HDD using Macrium Reflect and a Full/Differential backup plan.  The up-side was that the backups were made quite quickly.  The down-side was that the last couple of differentials failed (that was my first clue that the SSD was failing), and the total time to restore the images to a second HDD (including validating the backups until I found the last valid differential) was 4+ hours, and it killed the rest of my day.

I am looking for some way I can reliably back up my primary OS, even if it takes a long time (run it overnight) such that if I have another drive failure, I can hot-swap and lose only the last day's work.  Bonus if I can schedule it, or run it from a .BAT file, and double-bonus if the pieces are free, or already a part of the Windows 10 OS.

Comment: It almost sounds like you should consider a RAID 1 configuration and needs some redundancy for this particular need and not necessarily an automated core OS image to a standby HD but it is possible and able to be automated I'm sure using the free https://www.urbackup.org/ or even https://www.clonezilla.org/ but it'd take some time to get fully tested and automated but since I know both are possible without automation, I'm almost certain you could automate with either as a hot standby disk mounted to either Live OS with some scripts and such on a schedule...

Comment: It has been a while since I've done it and it was for a Windows Server but there is Windows software RAID you can configure as a RAID 1 for mirroring two drives so if one dies, the PC continues on with the other one. Additionally, you could have software RAID for redundancy and the continuity of your machine when one HD or SDD dies and still have separate image and/or file level backups. Perhaps you may want to read up on these, give it some deep thought, and then implement accordingly. I don't have the magic automation answer for you and it'd take me time to get one too per my first comment.

Comment: For URBackup I know if you have the client tool installed, you can make full image OS backups with a batch script while the PC is online and push it to a network drive and then with the URBackup boot disk, you can mount to an SMB drive via it's Linus shell and such and then push a specific image to a specific HD or SDD so you'd have to automate the restore of the image from Linux with shell scripts and not batch but it could still work. I don't think Clonezilla allows online images of running Windows and you have to boot to it to make the image backup so it may not work. Quick thoughts.

Comment: Last comment and sorry they are out of order, some reading on Windows 10 software RAID: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-mirrored-volume-file-redundancy-windows-10 but do tons of homework, research, testing, and be sure you have backups before you make any changes in case you hose it up you can at least revert it back.

Answer (score 0):

> [I] am looking for the least amount of down-time if the failure happens in the middle of the day...

#### Backups prevent data loss.  RAID arrays prevent productivity loss.

Don't stop backing up your data. But to prevent losing half a workday of time, consider using a RAID controller and two identical drives configured in RAID 1.  A budget conscious controller doesn't need to [cost more than $40](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003GS8VA4), though if you want true hardware-RAID (and the improved performance that comes with it) you can spend several hundred dollars.

With a RAID 1 array, the controller writes every change to both disks simultaneously. That means both disks are *identical* to each other 100% of the time.

Here's what the recovery scenario looks like with RAID 1:

1. 10:00 AM - You determine your drive is failing. Use the RAID controller software to identify the port # of the failing drive.
2. 10:05 AM - Shut down your computer.
3. 10:10 AM - Disconnect the data and power cable from the failing drive.
4. 10:15 AM - Start the computer using only the remaining good drive.

Now you can finish your workday and purchase a replacement drive at your (earliest) leisure. When it arrives, you shut down your computer, connect the new drive, follow the RAID controller's procedure to add it into your RAID 1 array, and it will automatically copy everything on the primary disk to the new one.

---

#### RAID arrays also offer other advantages:

- If the controller finds a bad block on a drive, it retrieves the good copy from the other drive then writes it to another location on the drive with the bad block. This makes your setup more resistant to data loss. This will also trigger an alert to the presence of the bad block.
- Better/more expensive controllers can fetch data from *both* drives during read operations, potentially doubling your system's read performance. Since most non-server workloads involve read operations the majority of the time, this can dramatically improve performance.